# Unable to make Window transparent in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, transparency

I have recently upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 12.10 (x64). 
I used to have transparent window tittle bar using `gconf-editor -> apps -> gwd`.
But in 12.10 editing the value isn't doing nothing.
Also in `ccsm` many plugins such as: opacity, brightness, saturation, desktop cube and rotate cube are all gone.
I love that transparent look very much and I want to get it back in 12.10.

I'm using Nvidia 7200GS ; AMD Athlon 7750 ; 3GB Ram.

Is there any way to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally I have solved the transparent window tittle problem using

`dconf editor`.
Anyone finding the same issue can find solution using my procedures.

instead of `gconf-editor` we have to use `dconf-editor`.

go to ..

```
dconf-editor --> org  --> compiz --> gwd
```

and set the value manually.
Works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this solve the missing plugin problem in ccsm :

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

But I am still out of luck with

```
gwd
```

Also the transparency of a window cannot be saved using '`opacity,brighness,saturation`'